# AWS Data Migration Service failing transformation rule for JSON operator

Tags: sqlite, aws-dms

Just getting started with AWS DMS. Having trouble writing a transformation rule using the '->>' operator. I am trying to extract a subcomponent of a json field at source and to add it as a column at destination. Tried using it directly in a transformation expression as well as wrapping it up in a case statement.

**1st try, (In a case statement)**

```
{
            "rule-type": "transformation",
            "rule-id": "3",
            "rule-name": "3",
            "rule-action": "add-column",
            "rule-target": "column",
            "object-locator": {
                "schema-name": "public",
                "table-name": "test"
            },
            "value": "client_name",
            "expression": "CASE WHEN details ->>'$.name' is not null THEN details ->>'$.name' ELSE '' END",
            "data-type": {
                "type": "string",
                "length": 50
            }
        }
```

**2nd try, (In simple select)**

```
{
            "rule-type": "transformation",
            "rule-id": "3",
            "rule-name": "3",
            "rule-action": "add-column",
            "rule-target": "column",
            "object-locator": {
                "schema-name": "public",
                "table-name": "test"
            },
            "value": "client_name",
            "expression": "select $details ->> '$.name' from public.test",
            "data-type": {
                "type": "string",
                "length": 50
            }
        }
```

3rd try (just using the operator)

```
    {
        "rule-type": "transformation",
        "rule-id": "3",
        "rule-name": "3",
        "rule-action": "add-column",
        "rule-target": "column",
        "object-locator": {
            "schema-name": "public",
            "table-name": "test"
        },
        "value": "Client_name",
        "expression": "$details ->> '$.name'",
        "data-type": {
            "type": "string",
            "length": 50
        }
    }
```

With all three examples, i'm getting errors related to the expression being wrong. How can I achieve what I am trying to?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, according to the AWS [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Tasks.CustomizingTasks.TableMapping.SelectionTransformation.Expressions.html) I don't see they support JSON expressions.